# Connect to AWS S3 bucket from Nodejs app ( persistent connection required)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-credentials

I have nodejs/express app from which I want to connect to AWS S3.

I do have a **temporary approach** to make connection,

**environment file**

```
aws_access_key_id=XXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXXX/
aws_session_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**S3-connection-service.js**

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: `${process.env.aws_access_key_id}`,
    secretAccessKey: `${process.env.aws_secret_access_key}`,
    sessionToken: `${process.env.aws_session_token}`,
    region: `${process.env.LOCAL_AWS_REGION}`
});

const S3 = new AWS.S3();

module.exports = {
    listBucketContent: (filePath) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const params = { Bucket: bucketName, Prefix: filePath };
            S3.listObjects(params, (err, objects) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(objects);
                }
            });
        }),
       ....
       ....
 }
```

**controller.js**

```
   const fetchFile = require("../../S3-connection-service.js");

   const AWSFolder = await fetchFile.listBucketContent(filePath);
```

Fine it's works and I'm able to access S3 bucket files and play with it.

**PROBLEM**

The problem is connection is not persistent. Since, I use **session_token**, connection remains alive for sometime and again after sometime new tokens will be generated, I have to copy-paste them in env file and re-run the node app.

***I really have no idea how can I make connection persistent ?***

Where to store AWS confidential/secrets and how to use them to connect to S3 so connection remains alive ?

Comment: Where and how is that app running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: `${process.env.aws_access_key_id}`,
    secretAccessKey: `${process.env.aws_secret_access_key}`,
    sessionToken: `${process.env.aws_session_token}`,
    region: `${process.env.LOCAL_AWS_REGION}`
});
```

code block from lambda source in file S3-connection-service.js

Attach a role to lambda function with proper permissions. You will have same functionally.

For local development.

You can set environment variable before testing your application.

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
```

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

If you are using any IDE you can set these environment variables on it.

If you are testing from cli

`$ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=EXAMPLE AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=EXAMPLEKEY AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2 npm start`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just created a role and using its accesskey and secretkey to get records from S3 bucket which is working fine. I still have doubt on the lambda function. How can I attach a role to lambda function ? fyi, I'm still using AWS.config.update({...}) but now I don't use `sessionToken` in it.

Comment: This video help you to attach/change lambda role https://youtu.be/T7cny-uyCuA  first part creation of role second part attach it to lambda

Answer (score 0):

> connect to S3 so connection remains alive ?

You can't make one request to S3 and keep it alive forever.

---

These are your options:

1. Add a try/catch statement inside your code to handle credentials expired error. Then, generate new credentials and re-initialize the S3 client.
2. Instead of using a Role, use a User. ([IAM Identities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id.html)). User credentials can be valid forever. You won't need to update the credentials in this case.
3. Do not provide the credentials to `AWS.config.update` like you are doing right now. If you don't provide the credentials, the AWS client will try to read them from your `~/.aws/credentials` file automatically. If you create a script to update them every hour (ex: a cronjob), then your credentials will be up-to-date at all times.

Comment: I have try/catch statement and I'm informing the user about token authentication failed.

Comment: Thanks for replying but it doesn't move me anywhere...

Comment: "I'm informing the user about token authentication failed" -> Who is the user? How can the user refresh the credentials?

What are the issues with the 2nd and 3rd options that they don't work for you?

Comment: There is no issue. I really have no idea how to proceed further. I have AWS login with me. I'll login and copy the tokens, change them in the application when it gets expired but as of now it is a manual process. I want to get rid of it and want to automate it. I really don't know how to proceed. Any reference link would also help me.

Comment: Where is your express app running? Is it on EC2?

Comment: I use Lambda + API gateway. My node/express code is within Lambda function. Lambda communicates with mysql to fetch data.

Comment: In that case you don't need to provide credentials at all. Set up a role for your Lambda with the required permissions and delete the AWS.config.update line and it will work. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-lambda.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but how can I handle it at development time. At dev time, I run node/express independently and from node, I want to connect to S3 bucket.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? I don't understand the concern. Are you asking about how to set up development and production stages?